# installation guidelines for sugar crm integration

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I want to integrate sugar CRM in my existing web application. I searched out about the installation process but I have some ambiguities in my mind.

Lets say my application is running on `www.myhost.com`. Now I want to  integrate the sugar CRM in my existing web. I found that download the sugar CRM and follow the installation wizard.

**Now** my question is that where to install the sugar CRM. Do I need to install it on any other web server? Because in installation process it is written that copy all the files of sugar CRM to your root folder. Do I have to have to have an other server for this? If so then how to integrate it my web application.

If on the same server where my application is running then, I am having my files of web on the root which is running on www.myhost.com then where to put these sugar crm?

Please guide me about it.

Regards.

Comment: Hi Awais, it's not clear if you've tried the things you're asking. Please either try them first or [edit] the question with the relevant details. Also, this question isn't a programming question and will most likely be closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugar will run from wherever you unpack the zip file, so long as it's inside a "web root" descendent directory.  So for instance, if this is your web root:

> /srv/www/

you could have sugar unpacked at:

> /srv/www/sugarcrm

or

> /srv/www/webapps/sugarcrm

or

> /srv/www/sugar/crm

So long as the http server can get to the index.php and install.php files, you should be good to go (and, of course, permissions in generally need to be set correctly, etc.)

Also, you can update your dns and vhosts so that `/srv/www/webapps/sugarcrm` can be reached via `crm.mywebsite.com`, etc.

Long story short, you can put unzip the file wherever, so long as apache or whatever you're running knows how to get to it and you know the URL to get apache there.

I have many a time simply cloned a production instance of Sugar by doing:

> cp /srv/www/sugar /srv/www/sugar/sandbox

and then cloned the db and updated the `config.php` file.  Then I just go to `mywebsite.org/sugar/` to get to production and `mywebsite.org/sugar/sandbox` to get to the clone.

Sugar is still striving toward true modularity, but in the case of the app itself, it's pretty much drag and drop.